# Which known Force users are not confirmed dead as of episode 7?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In the Disney canon there are many Force users, though fewer than Legends to be sure. How many of these characters could imaginably still be alive by the time of The Force Awakens?

Comment: Excluding Rey, Kylo and probably Snoke?

Comment: You could perhaps also count Leia, though she is not really trained.

Answer (score 2):

Luke Skywalker is the only one that comes to mind.

As for the Disney canon, there are no other force users really mentioned in the original trilogy, alive or dead.  Most of the current Disney canon revolving around force users is either pre-order 66 (Clone wars), or before episode IV (Rebels).

But from Rebels we have Asoka, Ezra and Kanan.

Comment: Being around pre-4 and not dead yet would be "not confirmed dead as of 7".

Comment: @Axerod considering the rebel series hasn't ended yet we can really say their fate

Comment: Exactly my point. Get compiling! You have incoming points to shovel!

Comment: I haven't watched it either! Google is your friend! You can do it!